# Date discrepancies in the 25K site analytics

Tags: bug, dates, site-analytics

Recently a [Normal Human](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/normal-human) posted the following messages to [one of our chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25623976#25623976):

> November 1 set the new record for the number of questions asked, with 854. Moreover, the top 10 days by the number of questions are all from October-November 2015.
>
> Prior to this Fall, the record was held by November 9, 2014, when 810 questions were asked.
>
> The record for the number of answers in a day is 1022, set on May 3, 2015. This is far ahead of the second place: November 9, 2014, when 989 answers were posted.
>
> However, I don't see any particularly large number of answers now, when searching `is:a created:2015-05-03`. Only 769 are shown, meaning that 253 of those 1022 answers were deleted. Was this a spam attack or a wave of low-quality answers?

Focusing on the issue of many "missing" answers from May 3, 2015, when I ran the 25K analytics on the site for May 2015, I got the following chart:

[image: 1022 answers posted on May 04, 2015]

To me it was May **4**, 2015 when we had the most answers posted (and, being a mod on math.se, searching `is:answer created:2015-05-04 deleted:all` confirmed this).

Furthermore, the other dates and data specified in these messages were similarly shifted by one day from what I saw in the analytics. (854 questions were asked on Nov 2, 2015; 810 questions were asked on Nov 10, 2014, 989 answers were posted on Nov 10, 2014.)

I might understand this user mis-typing once, but his being consistently off by one day (and my *strong suspicion* that we are located in widely separated time zones) makes me think that there is a bug in the handling of dates in the 25K site analytics tools.